# docusign insession some of issue in mobile browser open content extra space remove

Tags: laravel-8, docusignapi, docusignconnect

** Docusign insession open in mobile browser remove space **

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlGkP.png)

Answer (score 1):

The outlined space is how the banner looks like in screens with less than 768px width.

That's the default experience for smaller displays. You can notice the responsive layout if you switch to landscape mode.

Since it's not actually empty, as the "more options" from bottom left will fit in the space, it's not possible to remove or customize it.

Comment: machado you are right but my issue is docusign insesson load in iframe so i never changed to html dom not apply css to docusign this issue fixed in size (1910 * 655) to (320 * 420)